# Grabbing Dropdown Selection Parent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store the parent of a dropdown selection into a variable. I am able to do it using this line of code:

```
var myVariable = document.getElementById('mydropdownlist');
```

But I want to pull it using a selection in the dropdown list: So something like this, but it is not working

```
var mySecondVariable = $('select option:contains("New York")').parent();
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is with the second line of code?

Comment: Please post your markup too.

Answer (score 1):

the code is storing the `select` as an object that contains the `select` itself instead of storing it as an object of type HTMLSelectElement as you want, if you use

```
var mySecondVariable = $('select option:contains("New York")').parent()[0];
```

or

```
var mySecondVariable = $('select option:contains("New York")').parent().get(0);
```

it should work perfectly, although I'm not sure if there's any better solution, if so someone should state it.

[in jQuery FAQs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)